# ChromeでPost通信が失敗する

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

現在、IEの画面から従来のブラウザアドオンを有効にしたChromeを立上げ、Chromeにて外部カタログ画面へ遷移する開発を行っています。

POSTにて通信していますが、不定期でサブミットされたフォームの情報がなくなり、外部のカタログサイトへ遷移できない事象（以下、エラー）が発生しております。
エラーは毎回発生するものではなく、エラーが発生する際、１．パラメータがなくなり、２．POSTがGETに変更され、３．複数回リクエストが発行されております。
詳細は、添付画像を参照お願いいたします。

このエラーの解決策をお教えいただけないでしょうか。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なお、ブラウザアドオンを有効にしたChromeを事前に立ち上げた状態で、IEの画面からChromeにて外部カタログ画面へ遷移する場合は、エラーは発生しません。

Comment: IEからChromeを開くと言うのはあまり一般的ではないと思うのですが、どういつた手順でやっているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

今の段階だと可能性を絞ることしかできず恐縮なのですが、、、

①再現方法が明確に分かっているようでしたら教えてください
②chrome側は一時画面が残り、iframeとして新規タブが増えていくイメージでしょうか？
③構成がよく分からないので何ともなのですが、formのtarget がselfとなっていますが、一度開いた同じ画面でsubmit２回目以降もformの値は残っていますか？
④getになってしまっついるレスポンスデータを見るとカタログサイト上でリダイレクトされている様ですが、postの際に必要なcookieやパラメタが適切に引き継がれているでしょうか？(または不要なのに渡してしまっているなど)